# Get Name of Currently showed Page Layout - LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, metadata-api, page-layout, metadata

I'm currently working on building a LWC component that will generate and export word documents based on page layouts.

The component is exposed on object records, and pulls the recordId,Objectype etc to fetch the data that should be added to the word Document.

In the current implementation the user has to specify which page layout that should be used for structuring the document as a string in the component configuration.

What I'm wondering is if there some way to get the LWC to get the name of the Page Layout that is showing for the current user, without using the Tooling API?

I've tried the approach of using the `<lightning-record-edit-form />` to get some layout info. Unfortunetley it only returns the `layoutId`, and not the layout name.

The reason that i require the name is because I'm using the Metadata.operations.retrieve to fetch the metadata of the layout, and that operation requires the layout name in the format `ObjectApiName-LayoutName`, and not the id.

Any ideas?