Can we get the current page Layout name in the LWC/Apex?
Is there a way we can get page Layout name in lwc/Apex in which the component is added?

Have you checked this? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265256/how-to-get-page-layout-name-dynamically-in-apex   - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/387466/get-name-of-currently-showed-page-layout-lwc

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265256/how-to-get-page-layout-name-dynamically-in-apex --> This doesn't help as I am looking to get the layout name without any record type Id. as this component will be part of the managed package.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/387466/get-name-of-currently-showed-page-layout-lwc ---> I don't need the Id. I need the name without any dependency on the record Id.
